# What is causing my Android application to force close?

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to add a button, and have it switch layouts when clicked, but every time I run the app; it stops unexpectedly. I am very confused, if someone could help me that would be awesome.

Logcat messages -

```
01-02 18:41:54.844: W/dalvikvm(2070): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f00648)
01-02 18:41:54.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 18:41:54.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2070): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 18:41:54.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2070):     at sehej.android.doge.FullscreenActivity$3.onVisibilityChange(FullscreenActivity.java:82)
01-02 18:41:54.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2070):     at sehej.android.doge.util.SystemUiHiderHoneycomb$1.onSystemUiVisibilityChange(SystemUiHiderHoneycomb.java:113)
```

FullScreenActivity.java (Java file for home screen) -

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    public void button1_click(final View view)
    {
      startActivity(new Intent(this, MainGameActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
                HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {

                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {                         delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });
        };

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false; 
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (layout for home screen) -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grass"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:padding="20sp"
    app:textAlignment="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <View
        app:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        app:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        app:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        app:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <requestFocus
        app:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        app:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ButtonBar"
        app:layout_width="150dp"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        app:onClick="button1_click"
        app:text="@string/button1"
        app:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        app:id="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        app:text="@string/title"
        app:textColor="@color/blue"
        app:textSize="60sp"
        app:textStyle="bold"
        app:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        app:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/ButtonBar"
        app:layout_width="150dp"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        app:text="@string/button2"
        app:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageButton
        app:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        style="@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle"
        app:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        app:contentDescription="@string/dogepic_info"
        app:src="@drawable/doge" />

    <TextView
        app:id="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        app:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:text="@string/dogepic_caption"
        app:textColor="@color/green"
        app:textSize="15sp"
        app:textStyle="bold"
        app:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: _Please_ fix your formatting, this is really hard to read.

Comment: Its all in your logcat: 01-02 18:41:54.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2070): java.lang.NullPointerException 01-02 18:41:54.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2070): at sehej.android.doge.FullscreenActivity$3.onVisibilityChange(FullscreenActivity.java:82) 01-02 18:41:54.844: E/AndroidRuntime(2070): at . You should use debugger to investigate what is null in this funciton.

Comment: You're getting a NullPointerException in FullscreenActivity at line 82. With Android Studio, if you click on FullscreenActivity.java:82, it will take you directly to that line. That being said, remove the final keyword in front of your two views. Also,please reformat it properly (taking out all the comments to cut down on the space you're using, but showing us where the line 82 is located at with a comment).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, if i remove final from both views in FullscreenActivity.java, I get these three errors and one warning:                                  'Cannot refer to a non-final variable controlsView inside an inner class defined in a different method'
(At lines 83, 89, and 97).

And, 'The value of the local variable controlsView is not used'
(On line 60)

All four problems occur in FullscreenActivity.java

Comment: That's because your method required the View to be final when passed as a parameter. See my code below, where I fixed everything (but didn't check with a compiler, so those errors will be gone, but there may still be one or two remaining errors that you'll have to track down yourself with logcat).

Answer (score 0):

This method should be registered as an onClickListener inside onCreate(). Furthermore, its View parameter can not be final.

```
public void button1_click(final View view)
{
  startActivity(new Intent(this, MainGameActivity.class));
}
```

In other words, you should write:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;
    Button buttonView;
    View controlsView;
    View contentView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contentView = (View)findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        controlsView = (View)findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        buttonView = (View)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(myButtonHandler);

        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
                HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;
       }
       View.OnClickListener myButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           startActivity(new Intent(this, MainGameActivity.class));
       }
    };         
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {

                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView
                                .animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {                          
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });

    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, your way of declaring things isn't the best practice, you are getting a null pointer exception which means that something reference, variable etc.. is not found,initialized,declared or doesn't exists.. hope to help

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace gives you all the information you need to track down the error. Right at the top, two lines tell you that you tried to access a variable or method through a null reference:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sehej.android.doge.FullscreenActivity$3.onVisibilityChange(FullscreenActivity.java:82)
```

You've pasted the contents of this source file for us, as well as several more files, when only the area around line 82 was necessary. Of course, the stack trace tells you this, so learn to read it - it's an invaluable tool for debugging.

To help you get started, here are lines 81-83:

```
if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
    mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
}
```

On line 36 of your program you try to instantiate *controlsView* like so:

```
final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
```

Add a debugging statement after this line, printing the *controlsView* variable. Does it produce an object reference or "(null)"? If it is null, why do you think *findViewById()* might fail?